# How to run a powershell command using Azure Data Factory web Activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-vm

I am attempting to run a PowerShell command that creates a BACPAC backup of a database in an Azure VM, does anyone know how to pass the command to the VM through a web activity?
[image]

The connection is fine but how do I pass the script itself?

Comment: Not interested in Azure Batch solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Web activity` doesn't run PowerShell Script.

> Web Activity can be used to call a custom REST endpoint from an Azure
> Data Factory or Synapse pipeline. You can pass datasets and linked
> services to be consumed and accessed by the activity.

`Custom activity` is the only activity which can execute `Powershell` scripting. But as you mentioned that you are not interested in Azure Batch solutions.

So, you can go with `Azure Function` and run that function using `Azure Function activity` in the Azure Data Factory.

You can refer this third-party tutorial - [Running Powershell in Azure Functions](https://tminus365.com/running-powershell-in-azure-functions/) - to deploy a Azure Function and use [Azure Function activity in ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity) to run the Function in ADF.

Comment: Thank you for this complete and helpful answer! I was under the belief that you could post the script through the VM's Powershell via the API.